# Which one is more efficient of using array list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, memory-efficient

Which one is more efficient to instantiate a list ?

```
List<Type> list = new ArrayList<Type>(2);
list.add(new Type("one"));
list.add(new Type("two"));
```

OR

```
List<Type> list = Arrays.asList(new Type("one"), new Type("two"));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They create different types of objects. `new ArrayList<>()` creates a `java.util.ArrayList`, which can be added to, etc.

`Arrays.asList()` uses a type which happens to also be called `ArrayList`, but is a nested type (`java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`) and *doesn't* allow elements to be added or removed. It *just* wraps an array.

Now, if you don't care about those differences, you end up with two roughly-equivalent implementations, both wrapping an array in the `List<>` interface. I would be very surprised to see them differ in performance in any significant way - but as ever, if you have *specific* performance concerns, you should test them in your particular context.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that ArrayList from `Arrays.asList()` actually is another ArrayList than the java.util.ArrayList.

Comment: I didn't know that either... As it seems the 2 variants differ a bit in efficiency (at least on my machine). On 100 million runs the first variant needs ~ 1500 ms and the second ~ 900 ms